# CodeIgniter 3 : show_404() shows only template file and not controller

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have a controller where I need to check for valid ID in url and `show_404()` if ID doesn't match.

Where I am facing problem is when I call `show_404()` it only shows `view/error/404.html` and not custom `my404` controller which I configured in `routes.php`

Difference is `my404` controller adds header and footer with same `view/error/404.html`

Comment: Share `router.php` code you made for it.

Comment: Its simple, 
`$route['default_controller'] = 'home';`
`$route['404_override'] = 'my404';`
`$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;`

Answer (score 6):

To have a custom 404 page when calling show_404(), you'll need to extend the core.

When you simply add it to routes, it does not affect show_404().

In application/core folder:

```
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {

    /**
     * 404 Error Handler
     *
     * @uses    CI_Exceptions::show_error()
     *
     * @param   string  $page       Page URI
     * @param   bool    $log_error  Whether to log the error
     * @return  void
     */
    public function show_404($page = '', $log_error = TRUE)
    {
        if (is_cli())
        {
            // For CLI
            $heading = 'Not Found';
            $message = 'The controller/method pair you requested was not found.';
            echo $this->show_error($heading, $message, 'error_404', 404);
        }
        else
        {
            // For view
            $CI = &get_instance();
            $CI->layout->show('front/error/404', $CI->view_data); //Note I am using layout library. You'll probably use $CI->load->view()
            echo $CI->output->get_output();
        }

        // By default we log this, but allow a dev to skip it
        if ($log_error)
        {
            log_message('error', $heading.': '.$page);
        }

        exit(4); // EXIT_UNKNOWN_FILE
    }

}
```

Comment: I confirmed this works fine, but it's recommended to add $CI->output->set_status_header('404'); after  $CI = &get_instance();

Comment: This code will work OK, but not for CLI, because you have changed the output for CLI as well as HTML. You should be doing an if -> else type statement and outputing two different ways.